# obout Grid referesh Master Grid after update DetailGrid and keep expand DetailGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, obout

am using Obout Grid with asp.net c# we have a nested Obout Grid am editing Details Grid after perform the update we want refresh the Master Grid and after refresh we want keep the expand which is updated my Grid is

```
<obout:Grid ID="GrdVendor" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoPostBackOnSelect="false"
                    AllowSorting="false" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="false" Width="100%" Height="370px"
                    PageSize="0" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowPageSizeSelection="false">
                    <ScrollingSettings ScrollHeight="500" />
                    <Columns>
                        <obout:Column DataField="ORG_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Org ID">
                        </obout:Column>
                        <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="VENDOR ID">
                        </obout:Column>
                        <obout:Column DataField="ORGANIZATION_NAME" Visible="true" HeaderText="Organization Name"
                            Width="33%">
                        </obout:Column>
                        <obout:Column DataField="outstanding_amt" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Amt"
                            Width="33%" HeaderAlign="right" Align="right">
                        </obout:Column>
                        <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Req Amt"
                            Width="33%" HeaderAlign="right" Align="right">
                        </obout:Column>
                    </Columns>
                    <MasterDetailSettings LoadingMode="OnCallback" />
                    <DetailGrids>
                        <obout:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="GrdCategoryDetails" ForeignKeys="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,VENDOR_ID,ORG_ID"
                            AllowSorting="false" DataSourceID="vendor_Details" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
                            Width="98%" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowPageSizeSelection="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                            ShowCollapsedGroups="false" ShowFooter="true" AllowDataAccessOnServer="true"
                            OnUpdateCommand="GrdCategoryDetails_UpdateCommand">
                            <ScrollingSettings ScrollHeight="250" />
                            <ClientSideEvents OnClientUpdate="onCommand" ExposeSender="true" />
                            <Columns>
                                <obout:Column DataField="ORG_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Org ID" ReadOnly="true">
                                </obout:Column>
                                <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Vendor ID" ReadOnly="true">
                                </obout:Column>
                                <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE" Visible="true" HeaderText="Broker Type"
                                    ReadOnly="true" Width="33%">
                                </obout:Column>
                                <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Amt"
                                    HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" ReadOnly="true" Width="33%">
                                </obout:Column>
                                <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Req Amt"
                                    HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" Width="33%">
                                </obout:Column>
                                <obout:Column ID="Column1" AllowEdit="true" HeaderText="Edit" Width="100" runat="server">
                                </obout:Column>
                            </Columns>
                            <DetailGrids>
                                <obout:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="GrdvendorDetailsGrid" ForeignKeys="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,VENDOR_ID,ORG_ID"
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="false" DataSourceID="Vendor_Details1"
                                    PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" Width="98%" AllowAddingRecords="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <obout:Column DataField="ORG_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Org ID" ReadOnly="true">
                                        </obout:Column>
                                        <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_ID" Visible="false" HeaderText="Vendor ID" ReadOnly="true">
                                        </obout:Column>
                                        <%--<obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE" Visible="true" HeaderText="Broker Type"
                                    ReadOnly="true" Width="25%">
                                </obout:Column>--%>
                                        <obout:Column DataField="VENDOR_NAME" Visible="true" HeaderText="Vendor Name" ReadOnly="true"
                                            Width="33%">
                                        </obout:Column>
                                        <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Amt"
                                            HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" ReadOnly="true" Width="33%">
                                        </obout:Column>
                                        <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" Visible="true" HeaderText="Outstanding Req Amt"
                                            HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" Width="33%">
                                        </obout:Column>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <DetailGrids>
                                        <obout:DetailGrid runat="server" ID="GrdInvoiceDetailsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                            AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10"
                                            ForeignKeys="VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,VENDOR_ID,ORG_ID" Width="98%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_InvoiceDetails">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="INVOICE_ID" HeaderText="Invoice ID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="ORG_ID" HeaderText="ORG_ID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="ORGANIZATION_NAME" HeaderText="Organization Name" Wrap="true"
                                                    ReadOnly="true" Width="18%">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="PROJECT_DESCRIPTIONS" HeaderText="Project" Wrap="true" Width="12%"
                                                    ReadOnly="true">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="INVOICE_NUM" HeaderText="Invoice Num" Wrap="true" ReadOnly="true"
                                                    Width="12%">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="INVOICE_DATE" HeaderText="Invoice Date" Wrap="true" ReadOnly="true"
                                                    Width="13%" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="INVOICE_AMT" HeaderText="Invoice Amt" Wrap="true" ReadOnly="true"
                                                    HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" Width="13%">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_AMT" HeaderText="Outstanding Amt" Wrap="true"
                                                    HeaderAlign="right" Align="right" Width="15%" ReadOnly="true">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                                <obout:Column DataField="OUTSTANDING_REQ_AMT" HeaderText="Outstanding Req Amt" Wrap="true"
                                                    HeaderAlign="right" Width="15%" Align="right">
                                                </obout:Column>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </obout:DetailGrid>
                                    </DetailGrids>
                                </obout:DetailGrid>
                            </DetailGrids>
                        </obout:DetailGrid>
                    </DetailGrids>
                </obout:Grid>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function onCommand(sender, record) {
        var masterGrid = getMasterGrid(sender.ID, null);
        window.setTimeout(masterGrid.ID + '.refresh();', 250);
    }

    function getMasterGrid(detailGridId, currentGrid) {
        if (!currentGrid) {
            currentGrid = GrdVendor;
        }

        if (currentGrid.DetailGrids) {
            for (var i = 0; i < currentGrid.DetailGrids.length; i++) {
                if (currentGrid.DetailGrids[i].ID == detailGridId) {
                    return currentGrid;
                } else {
                    var masterGrid = getMasterGrid(detailGridId, currentGrid.DetailGrids[i]);
                    if (masterGrid != null) {
                        return masterGrid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated your example and here is my answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var expandedDetailsIndexes = '';

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function () {
                if (oldonload) {
                    oldonload();
                }
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    function AttachEvents() {
        oboutGrid.prototype.manageDetailGridsExpandedState_old = oboutGrid.prototype.manageDetailGridsExpandedState;
        oboutGrid.prototype.manageDetailGridsExpandedState = function (obj) {
            var currentRow = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
            this.manageDetailGridsExpandedState_old(obj);
            storeExpandedDetails(this.ID, this.getElementIndex(currentRow));
        }
    }

    function storeExpandedDetails(gridId, rowIndex) {
        var expandedDetails = expandedDetailsIndexes;

        var existingElement = false;
        if (expandedDetails != '') {
            var arrExpandedDetails = expandedDetails.split(',');

            var gridBaseId = gridId;

            if (gridBaseId.indexOf('_') != -1) {
                gridBaseId = gridId.substr(0, gridId.indexOf('_'));
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < arrExpandedDetails.length; i += 2) {
                if (arrExpandedDetails[i].indexOf(gridBaseId) == 0) {
                    arrExpandedDetails[i] = gridId;
                    arrExpandedDetails[i + 1] = rowIndex;

                    existingElement = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            var arrExpandedDetails = new Array();
        }

        if (!existingElement) {
            arrExpandedDetails.push(gridId);
            arrExpandedDetails.push(rowIndex);
        }

        expandedDetailsIndexes = arrExpandedDetails.join(',');
    }

    function restoreExpandedDetails(tempExpandedDetails) {
        if (tempExpandedDetails != '') {
            var arrExpandedDetails = tempExpandedDetails.split(',');

            var gridId = arrExpandedDetails.shift();
            var rowIndex = arrExpandedDetails.shift();

            try {
                var grid = eval(gridId);
                grid.getExpandCollapseDetailsButtonForRow(grid.GridBodyContainer.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes[1].childNodes[rowIndex]).onclick();
                tempExpandedDetails = arrExpandedDetails.join(',');
            } catch (ex) {
            }

            window.setTimeout(function () { restoreExpandedDetails(tempExpandedDetails); }, 500);
        }
    }


    function onCommand(sender, record) {
        var masterGrid = getMasterGrid(sender.ID, null);
        eval(masterGrid.ID + '.refresh();');
        window.setTimeout(function () {             
            restoreExpandedDetails(expandedDetailsIndexes);
        }, 250);
    }

    function getMasterGrid(detailGridId, currentGrid) {
        if (!currentGrid) {
            currentGrid = GrdVendor;
        }

        if (currentGrid.DetailGrids) {
            for (var i = 0; i < currentGrid.DetailGrids.length; i++) {
                if (currentGrid.DetailGrids[i].ID == detailGridId) {
                    return currentGrid;
                } else {
                    var masterGrid = getMasterGrid(detailGridId, currentGrid.DetailGrids[i]);
                    if (masterGrid != null) {
                        return masterGrid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    addLoadEvent(function () {
        AttachEvents();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First Thanks for the rply,                                                                            we want Refresh the Parent Grid after perform the Update on child Grid that is not working on your Code

Comment: @AT How is not refreshing when I call masterGrid.ID + '.refresh();';?

Comment: its throw the Error                                                                            Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Give the syntax :-var arrExpandedDetails = expandedDetails.split(',');

Comment: can u explain me this syntax                                                                          var expandedDetails = expandedDetailsIndexes;

Comment: @AT Ok, I've updated my answer because it had a minor issue. In my code I just bind to obout events to store indexes or expanded rows and then restore them after grid refresh.